# NumberFormatException:null

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee

Now I have been stuck by an error which shows the following error in the Eclipse browser.The Error looks like:

```
13:53:12,294 INFO  [STDOUT] 30
13:53:12,294 ERROR [[Expthsmon]] Servlet.service() for servlet Expthsmon threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Expthsmon.doGet(Expthsmon.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I believe that this part of the code

```
int amountofnoon=0;
    int amountofafternoon=0;
    int noofnoon=0;
    int noofafternoon=0;
    String amountnoon=null;
    String amountafternoon=null;
    amountnoon=request.getParameter("amountnoon");
    amountafternoon=request.getParameter("amountafternoon");
    //if((amountnoon !=null )&&(amountafternoon !=null))

     amountofnoon=Integer.parseInt(amountnoon);
     System.out.println(""+amountofnoon);
     amountofafternoon=Integer.parseInt(amountafternoon);
     System.out.println(""+amountofafternoon);
```

is creating problem,where amountofnoon and amountofafternoon should be integer value.What should I do?

I am also adding the jsp part of code from where it is getting the value:

```
<form name="expenditurefthsmon" action="Expthsmon">
<div align="center">Enter The Amount of Days Expenditure</div>
 <div align="center"><input type="text"  name="amountnoon"></input></div>
 <div align="center">Enter The Amount of Nights Expenditure</div>
<div align="center"><input type="text" name=amountafternoon"></input></div>
 <div align="center"><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></input></div>"
</form>
```

Comment: The problem is that one of your parameters is missing. You should test it's present before you try to parse it.

Comment: One thing worth mention is that,the amountofnoon is printing the correct given input,whereas amountofafternoon is not printing the given input.

Comment: Most likely, one of your parameters isn't defined resulting in passing `null` to `parseInt` - hence your error.

Comment: You don't have "amountofafternoon" in your code, only "amountafternoon" (missing *of*)!

Comment: What is line 44 of Expthsmon.java? I'm assuming that's your class

Comment: It's funny to inform you that the problem is resolved and what's more funny is the way it is resolved.I just changed the variablename of jsp page "amountafternoon" to "amountanoon" and the problem is gone!!I don't why this happened....but at the end I am happy problem is resolved!Thanks everyone for their help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code in your html misses a quotation mark for the name attribute

```
<div align="center"><input type="text" name=amountafternoon"></input></div>
```

It should be

```
<div align="center"><input type="text" name="amountafternoon"></input></div>
```

Other than that, you must never trust the input from the user and always validate it againts invalid or null values before going into your core logic.

Answer (score 2):

`amountnoon` AND/OR `amountafternoon` has value `null`, You need to validate request parameters for its nullity

Answer (score 1):

you should check for null value. e.g.

```
if(amountnoon != null){
    amountofnoon=Integer.parseInt(amountnoon);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, one of these two calls returns `null`:

```
amountnoon=request.getParameter("amountnoon");
amountafternoon=request.getParameter("amountafternoon");
```

Trying logging/printing these two values before passing them to `Integer.parseInt`.

If you pass `null` to `parseInt`, you'll get a `NumberFormatException: null` error as you described.